# What would be a more literary and/or formal way of saying "hanging out with friends"?

Tags: phrase-requests, formality

I am writing an essay which includes my hobbies in high school; I know this is pretty common but I would like a more literary and/or formal way of saying this.

> My hobbies include *{hanging out with friends}*

[Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/hanging%20out?s=t) gives phrases related to locations rather than people, or about being friends with people rather than spending time with them.

Comment: Hello Aponom.  Welcome to ELU.  We ask that you explain what research you have done trying to find an answer.  Then we'll try to help.

Comment: Hi aponom. Welcome to ELU. I think you have a good question here, so I've edited it to be more in line with the sort of thing that makes a good question; namely included research and given an example sentence.

Comment: If I may make a friendly suggestion, I wouldn't consider *hanging out with friends* to be a *hobby*; that word has connotations of an interest or activity where you are refining your tastes or improving a skill— putting in some kind of effort, unlike *watching TV* or *eating out*. That said, you can easily couch *hanging out* as an activity that curmudgeons like me do accept, maybe you're on a softball team together, or you debate current affairs, just like you can apply artistic pretensions to your Netflix queue and your carryout menus.

Answer (score 3):

This is kind of difficult.

There are other *casual* phrases, such as

> I like **spending time** with my friends.

But that is certainly not formal enough.

However, anything formal on that score is almost certain to come off as mockery. Consider:

> I am **very fond of social engagements**.

Or:

> **Socializing** is one of my hobbies.

Or:

> **Mingling** is one of my favorite activities.

Or:

> I spend a great deal of my spare time **hobnobbing with my associates**.

The answer, in my opinion, is

**leaving it as it is**

OR (this is important!)

**skipping it altogether**.

Most people like to hang out. It is not one of those unique traits that could automatically pique an objective reader's curiosity.

Last but not least, mentioning that you're ***sociable*** might come off as a bit ambiguous.

This, of course, is merely my opinion, which I hereby encourage you to ignore.

Comment: "Socialising" gets my vote, but plenty of other good suggestions in here too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're asking for something literary / formal, consider saying that you enjoy *visiting with* your friends.

> **visit with sb** *phrasal verb*
>   to spend time talking with someone you know:
>   My grandmother was visiting with one of her friends on the porch.
>   [- Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/visit-with-sb)

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna get a bit grandiose, you could claim:

> attending a symposium of my peers

Using the older definition of `symposium` meaning:

> n. A drinking party, especially one with intellectual discussion.

*[Wordnik](https://www.wordnik.com/words/symposium)*

Answer (score 0):

to **associate** with  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/associate)

> To spend time socially; keep company: